# How to automatically run a specific program when another specific program is closed?

Tags: autohotkey

I want `ahk_exe QTranslate.exe` to be running automatically in system tray as soon as another program `ahk_exe pycharm64.exe` is closed.

I've tried this:

```
Loop {    
  if WinExist("ahk_exe pycharm64.exe") 
  WinWaitClose, ahk_exe pycharm64.exe    
  Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\QTranslate\QTranslate.exe",,hide    
}
```

The problem with this is that the `QTranslate` window always appears continuously, and when I close it, It appears and appears without stopping, and `QTranslate` does not start running in the system tray, that happens when `ahk_exe pycharm64.exe` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Persistent

SetTimer, run_QTranslate, 500
    return

    run_QTranslate:
If ProcessExist("QTranslate.exe")
    return ; do nothing
; otherwise:
If ProcessExist("pycharm64.exe") 
{
    Process, WaitClose, pycharm64.exe
    SetTimer, run_QTranslate, Off  ; turns the timer off
    Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\QTranslate\QTranslate.exe",,hide 
    Process, WaitClose, QTranslate.exe
    SetTimer, run_QTranslate, On  ; for next time pycharm64.exe exists
}
return

ProcessExist(name){
    Process, Exist, %name%
        return Errorlevel
}
```